Need help identifying a couple of IC's
I've got a couple of IC's here that I've tried doing the usual web-seach on the numbers and nothing comes up.  These chips are on a board found in a smart wall-switch made by "Incipio".  This switch was likely new or current back in 2017.  Even identifying the maker from the logo would be a good start.


This is from an Incipio Commandkit Smart Wall Switch. A date silkscreened on the board is August 2017, and on the box is a (c) 2017. It's a dimmer switch, it can do power metering and sense proximity (or occupancy?) via what I think is an IR sensor.  The WIFI part is done by a small IOT board - WACIO GP ( iCOM ) 2.4GHz Wi-Fi module which I've removed, hoping to replace it with an ESP8266. These switches found their way to the dollar store in 2019/2020 as they were liquidated. On the box it says Designed in USA, made in China.
Since it says on the box that it can do metering, one of these chips must be for power measuring.

Since you say it's from 2017 or so, the last 4 digits are probably the date code.
